# Displaying location in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, united-states

I have a CSV file containing a location that I want to display as a point shapefile in ArcMap. The points are listed below. These points were collected 30 years back. I tried displaying using Add XY in ArcMap using the given number using given coordinate system and other (hit and trial).

These points were collected in Saline County, Illinois but it wont overlap to the area I want. How can I overlap this? Or turn this Northing/Easting to Decimal degrees?

```
Location,   Northing,   Easting
1,  13675437.59,    1225367.09
2,  13675608.01,    1225493.01
3,  13675308.9, 1226357.12
4,  13675152.05,    1226472.95
5,  13675008.42,    1225503.05
6,  13674557.87,    1227937.08
7,  13674578.43,    1227561.57
8,  13675814.73,    1229842.33
9,  13674915.99,    1227993.79
10, 13675194.05,    1228282.82
11, 13675899.52,    1229449.86
12, 13674169.69,    1225017.71
13, 13673284.89,    1224497.81
14, 13675742.49,    1230254.75
15, 13675821.2, 1230511.42
16, 13675778.08,    1229272.59
17, 13675601.44,    1228832.93
18, 13673977.6, 1224590.22
19, 13675487.14,    1225779.19
20, 13675334.23,    1225771.35
```

These locations has the datum and coordinate information as follows:

```
Datum: NAD-83
Coordinate System:Universal Transverse Mercator[16S]
Altitude Mode: MSL
Altitude/Distance Units:Feet
Velocity Units: Miles/Hour
```

Comment: The "S" refers to the latitude band of UTM16. Look [Here](https://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a UTM83-16IF(International Foot) coordinate system, the points are a bit southeast of Harrisburg, Illinois in Saline County.
[image]

This projection that I used in AutoCAD Civil 3D doesn't have an EPSG or other number. You can create a custom projection in ArcMap with this:

PROJCS["UTM83-16IF",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.000,298.25722210],TOWGS84[0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.00000000]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",1640419.948],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.000],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-87.00000000000000],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.000],UNIT["Foot",0.30480000000000]]

Comment: Thank you, and this seems correct, but is this projection system available in ArcMap 10.9?

Comment: I added the WKT in my answer. You can use that to create the UTM83-16IF projection.

Comment: Thank you !! It worked fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Your information or your coordinate values are incorrect.  [NAD83 UTM 16S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system) would reference a coordinate system that is south of the equator. It is unlikely that someone would have used UTM 16S for Illinois data.

Assuming the correct UTM zone for Saline County (NAD 83 16N) these points would not plot anywhere near Saline County.  The UTM coordinates for Harrisburg, IL are:
[image]

Assuming the data are not in UTM but rather Illinois State Plane East (or West) the coordinate values are again, not near Saline County, IL.

You need to sort out the correct coordinate reference system or re-evaluate the northing and easting values.